# Can I find the definition of Jager's ordinal collapsing functions?

Tags: ordinal-numbers

http://cantorsattic.info/index.php?title=J%C3%A4ger%27s_collapsing_functions_and_%CF%81-inaccessible_ordinals&action=edit

Sadly, Cantor's attic is making an error. This is all I know about Jager's ordinal collapsing functions.

I know it is in [the paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02007140), but it is not free. I want to know about the ordinal notation from Jager's ordinal collapsing functions.

Comment: isn't this the paper? (seems open access): https://publikationen.badw.de/de/001077193.pdf

Comment: @CarloBeenakker "the paper" is actually https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02007140 . I fix the question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank Carlo Beenakker for the comment.

I can see Jäger's function in [Googology Wiki](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/J%C3%A4ger%27s_function?oldid=278807), now. This page is the revival of Cantor's Attic.